Bug on Divi Theme Shortcode got stuck on top
I've build a custom plugin. I'm trying to add the content using shortcode through html on divi theme. But, When I add shortcode it stuck in top. Can anyone help me
The content should be come into bottom where are placedThe content should be come into bottom where are placed.
